# Dis connect websocket in c# after many minutes

Tags: c#, websocket

I made a desktop program with c# an use 
web socket ((use : https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocketSharp/1.0.3-rc11)) into
and server side script  is PHP web socket ((use : http://socketo.me/))
but I encountered some errors.

1-When I call the Send method, the readyState switches to 'close' and I have to call Connect method before Send .

2-When The program stays idle for a while connection is close

Please help me 2 errors.
Thank you very much

my code c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using WebSocketSharp;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:4563");

        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public int request_id;    
        public bool online;

        public async Task<String> login(String id, String password)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "id",id },
                { "password",password }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/Login", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseString;
        }

        public void websocket()
        {
            button1.Enabled = button4.Enabled = button5.Enabled = false;

            ws.OnOpen += (sende, E) =>
            {
                //conncect app

            };

            ws.OnClose += (sende, E) =>
            {

            };

            ws.OnMessage += (sende, E) =>
            {
                dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(E.Data);

                switch ((String)response.type)
                {
                    case "push_for_app":
                        {
                            label10.Text = (String)response.response;
                            turn_count = (String)response.response;
                            if ((String)response.response == "0")
                            {
                                button1.Enabled = button4.Enabled = button5.Enabled = false;
                            }
                            else if (online) button1.Enabled = true;
                        }
                        break;


                    case "request":
                        {
                            switch ((String)response.method)
                            {
                                case "logout":
                                    {
                                        if ((String)response.response == "true")
                                        {
                                            groupBox1.Visible = false;
                                            groupBox4.Visible = false;
                                            groupBox1.Visible = false;
                                            groupBox4.Visible = false;
                                            groupBox2.Visible = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;


                                case "get_turn_count":
                                    {
                                        label10.Text = (String)response.response;
                                        turn_count = (String)response.response;
                                        if ((String)response.response == "0")
                                        {
                                            button1.Enabled = button4.Enabled = button5.Enabled = false;
                                        }
                                        else if (online) button1.Enabled = true;
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "set_online":
                                    {
                                        if ((String)response.response == "is_online")
                                        {
                                            button2.Visible = true;
                                            online = true;
                                            {
                                                var template = new
                                                {
                                                    type = "request",
                                                    method = "get_turn_count"
                                                };

                                                String output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template);
                                                ws.Connect();
                                                ws.Send(output);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "set_offline":
                                    {
                                        if ((String)response.response == "is_offline")
                                        {
                                            button8.Visible = true;
                                            button1.Enabled = false;
                                            online = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;


                                default: break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    default: break;
                }
            };

            var List = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> {
                    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("api-key", "jshTRHNSDB54n7y4e5nhty"),
                    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("secret-key", secret_key),
                    new KeyValuePair<String, String>("type", "app")
                    };
            ws.CustomHeaders = List;
            ws.Connect();

        }
        //login
        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<String> task = Task.Run(async () => await login(textBox1.Text, textBox3.Text));
            task.Wait();
            dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(task.Result);

            if (res.state == "true")
            {
                secret_key = res.message;
                set_secret(secret_key);
                groupBox1.Visible = true;
                groupBox4.Visible = true;
                groupBox2.Visible = false;
                button8.Visible = true;
                //connect socket
                websocket();
            }
            else { label11.Text = res.message; }
        }
        //start app
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Location = new Point(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width - this.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height - this.Height);
            this.BringToFront();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Focus();
        }

        //set offline
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var template = new
            {
                type = "request_from_pharmacy",
                method = "set_offline"
            };

            String output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template);

            ws.Connect();
            ws.Send(output);

            button2.Visible = false;
            button8.Visible = true;
        }  

        //set online
        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var template = new
            {
                type = "request",
                method = "set_online"
            };

            String output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template);

            ws.Connect();
            ws.Send(output);

            button8.Visible = false;
            button2.Visible = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: shows us your code

Comment: Yes, socket based connections are often severed due to inactivity. The time delay may depend on the service. Have you tried sending a dummy message periodically to keep things alive? The web-socket protocol includes a ping frame, but frankly it is more common to see a data frame used for the purpose.